# Are two circumferences with one point in common homeomorphic to R with this topology?

Tags: general-topology

On a topology space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, a *neighbourhood basis* $B$ of a point $x\in X$ is a collection of neighbourhoods of $x$ such that for every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ exists $U\in B$ which $U\subset V$. In addtition, an *opened neighbourhood basis* $B$ of a point $x$ is a neighbourhood basis such that $B\subset \mathcal{T}$.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the topology of $\Bbb{R}$ given by the following opened neighbourhood basis:

1. For $a\in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, the open intervals containing $a$ and not $0$
2. For $0$, the sets of the form:
   $$(-\infty,-n) \cup \left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right) \cup (n, \infty)$$Where $n$ is any positive integer.

Prove that $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ is homeomorphic to the union of two circumferences with one point in common.

I have been trying to prove that $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space of $[-1,1]$ with the equivalence relation:
$$xRy \Leftrightarrow x=y \text{ or } x,y \in \{-1,0,1\}$$

and then prove that this space (with the usual topology) is homeomorphic to the two circunferences:

$$f: [-1,1] \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}^2 $$

$$f(t)= \begin{cases} (-1+\cos(2\pi (t+1)), \sin(2\pi (t+1)) &, t \in [-1,0] \\(1+\cos(\pi(-2t+1),\sin(\pi(-2t+1)) &, t\in [0,1] \end{cases}$$

If am not mistaken, this function is continuous because its projections are continuous, and $f([-1,1])$ is the union of the unit circumferences centered in $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

I am having many issues with this problem, possible answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between "neighborhood basis" and "open neighborhood basis"? Aren't all neighborhoods of any point open by definition?

Comment: @K.Jiang The definition that I have learnt is a neighbourhood of a point of a topological space is a subset of the space which contains the point and an open set who also contains the point. For example, in the usual topology $[-1,1]$ is neighbourhood of $0$ because $0\in (-1,1) \subset [-1,1]$ but it is not an opened neighbourhood.

Comment: Your idea with the quotient space is good, but to carry it out you must construct the actual quotient map, i.e. you must right down a formula for that map. Have you tried that?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, in fact I have a function that could be a possibility, let me do an update of the post

Comment: $f$ is continuous by the pasting lemma. It is also surjective and indeed a quotient map.